# Synonym to constrained type

Tags: haskell, types, constraints, synonym

I know I can create synonym for a type, for example:

```
type ListToArray a e = [e] -> a Int e
```

I also read that a constrained type is still a type, so I thought I can create a synonym for that too:

```
type (Data.Array.IArray.IArray a e) => ListToArray a e = [e] -> a Int e
```

However GHC complains:

```
parse error on input '=>'
```

Does GHC support synonyms to constrained types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the [Haskell 2010 Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-630004.1), the section about type synonyms states that the grammar for type synonyms is:

```
type simpletype = type
simpletype  →   tycon tyvar1 … tyvark       (k ≥ 0)
```

In other words: no you cannot put class constraints on the left of the `=` in a `type` declaration.

Also note that you cannot have class constraints even on the right of the `=` in such declarations. The definition of `type` is:

```
type    →   btype [-> type]         (function type)

btype   →   [btype] atype       (type application)

atype   →   gtycon
    |   tyvar
    |   ( type1 , … , typek )       (tuple type, k ≥ 2)
    |   [ type ]        (list type)
    |   ( type )        (parenthesised constructor)

gtycon  →   qtycon
    |   ()      (unit type)
    |   []      (list constructor)
    |   (->)        (function constructor)
    |   (,{,})      (tupling constructors)
```

So the `type` non-terminal refers to a type *without a context*. In other words: no you cannot have a context in a type synonym, at least not in the general case.

GHC has a lot of extension to Haskell's type system that can lift some of the above restrictions in certain situations (see [this](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html) page.) however, AFAIK, none that achieves exactly what you want.